# Javascript loop showing same value 10 times

Tags: javascript, loops

Why is this function only sending the number 10 ten times. I want it to send 1... 2 ... 3 ... 4 ... 5  and so on 
but instead its showing
10....10.... 10... 10... I'm not sure why it would. 
How do I make a loop that returns distinct values?

```
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  setTimeout(function() { alert("test"+i.toString()) ; }, 100);
                                                                              }
```

How do I make a loop that returns distinct values?

Comment: By the time the timeout is in effect i has already reached the maximum value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a closure (pass `i` back into an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)). This will maintain the value of `i`:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("test" + i);
    }, 100);
  })(i);
}
```

To increment the timeout by using the `i` works the same way. Making sure to wrap the entire timeout call with the IIFE:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("test" + i);
    }, i * 100);
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: Yes this works =) is there anyway I can closure i to also increment the set time out? i*100 for instance?

Comment: @PeterSMcIntyre, yep, easy to do by moving all of the setTimeout code into the IIFE. Check updated answer.